# Javascript function call on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
    function next()
    {
    alert("form submited");
    return true;

    }

<form onsubmit="return next()" action="add.php" method="post" id="p1">
    <center>Add New Survey</center>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Title:    </p>
    <textarea name="title" cols="2" class="inputs" id="title"></textarea>
    <p align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Discription: (Optional)    </p>
    <textarea name="dis" cols="2" class="inputs" id="dis"></textarea>
     <p align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Number of questions:    </p>

    <select class="inputs" id="options" onchange="run()" name="options">
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" >3</option>
    <option value="4" >4</option>
    <option value="5" >5</option>
    </select>
    <br />

          <input type="Submit" value="Next" class="button" name="next"/>
      </p>
  </form>
```

Here is my code, i want to alert "form submitted" through JavaScript function. when i submit the form, nothing happen. i should alert the string.

Comment: Is the javascript code between `<script>function next()...</script>` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like it is because of the button name `next` which is the same as the function name.

In your console you should be seeing an error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

```
<input type="Submit" value="Next" class="button" name="somethingelse" />
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y2Cr7/1/), [Soution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y2Cr7/)

If you log the value of `next` in the `onsubmit` handler, it will refer to the `next` element, [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y2Cr7/3/).